# Was the "U" in Urbs pronounced as "ʊ" in classical pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, vowel

I noticed that on Wiktionary and on Wikipedia it says that the "U" in Urbs was pronounced as "ʊ". I thought that Latin didn't have these kinds of lax vowels? Wouldn't it be pronounced as [u] instead of as [ʊ]?

Answer (score 11):

Phonemically and historically speaking, the distinction between *u* and *ū* seems to have been solely one of length. When you lengthen a *u* (like before `/ns/`), you get a *ū*; when you shorten a *ū* (like before `/nt/`), you get a *u*. In Sardinian, the first Romance language to split off the family tree, *u* and *ū* merged. So it must have originally been something like `[u]`.

In terms of Classical-era phonetics, though, it seems *u* was significantly lower than *ū*—in fact, closer in quality to *ō* than to *u*! When Latin names are transcribed into Greek, *u* is transcribed with ο (e.g. Mummius who sacked Corinth becomes Μόμμιος in Greek sources). And when vowel length was lost in Vulgar Latin, *u* and *ō* merged, while *ū* and *o* remained separate from the pair.

As a result, `[ʊ]` is the most common way of transcribing *u* phonetically. We may not be sure of the exact pronunciation, but we know it was derived from `[u]`, and closer to `[o]` than to `[u]`.

Comment: This link also gives "incipit" as an example for [ɪ], surely that's a lot more dubious?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Latin

Comment: @Nomad1004 Just as _ō_ and _u_ merged in Romance, so did _ē_ and _i_, in fact! So it seems short _i_ was also closer to _ē_ in quality than to _ī_.